# Unity game weird crash on Samsung S22 Android 12: libGLESv2 call vulkan while using opengles2/3

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I built a game with Unity 2020.3.37f1c1, but I've been getting some weird crashes recently.

libunity called 'EGL_ClientWaitSyncKHR' of 'libGLESv2_samsung.  so', and finally crashed in /vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.samsung.so.

Currently only appears on Samsung S22(Android 12)

The following is the wrong stack information and attachment:

```
Exception java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 2020.3.37f1c1
Device model      : samsung SM-S901B
Device fingerprint: samsung/r0sxeea/r0s:12/SP1A.210812.016/S901BXXU2AVG6:user/release-keys
Build Type        : Release
Scripting Backend : IL2CPP
ABI               : arm64-v8a
Strip Engine Code : true

Caused by: java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.3.37f1c1 (9f30be21c416)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/r0sxeea/r0s:12/SP1A.210812.016/S901BXXU2AVG6:user/release-keys'
Revision: '28'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2022-08-11 16:26:01+0100
pid: 31315, tid: 31510, name: UnityMain  >>> com.joy.dreams <<<
uid: 10353
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x18
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  b40000730ca851a8  x1  0000000000000001  x2  b4000073c685e958  x3  0000000000000001
    x4  0000000002faf080  x5  0000007389af81f4  x6  000000739307cd74  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  00000072e05e5930  x9  0000000000000000  x10 000000000000148e  x11 00000076d3767038
    x12 00000076d3767030  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 0000000000236ca0  x15 000000ff43beb615
    x16 000996cc2fb00000  x17 0000000027100000  x18 0000007223726000  x19 0000000002faf080
    x20 0000000000000001  x21 b4000073c685e960  x22 b40000730ca851a8  x23 00000072e05e5930
    x24 b4000075d6845030  x25 00000072e05e6000  x26 0000000000000001  x27 00000000000fc000
    x28 00000072e04ed000  x29 00000072e05e5950
    sp  00000072e05e5930  lr  0000007393046400  pc  0000007389af5678

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000013fc678  /vendor/lib64/hw/vulkan.samsung.so (BuildId: 3c3f650bfd63758b76be354f30896f41c5962e82)
      #01 pc 00000000003f73fc  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_samsung.so (BuildId: a637a476c6448ffa)
      #02 pc 00000000004229c8  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_samsung.so (BuildId: a637a476c6448ffa)
      #03 pc 000000000042d0d4  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_samsung.so (BuildId: a637a476c6448ffa)
      #04 pc 000000000042ddb8  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_samsung.so (BuildId: a637a476c6448ffa)
      #05 pc 00000000002322f4  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_samsung.so (BuildId: a637a476c6448ffa)
      #06 pc 000000000023a5fc  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_samsung.so (EGL_ClientWaitSyncKHR+128) (BuildId: a637a476c6448ffa)
      #07 pc 0000000000e21048  /data/app/~~udK_hURMFPtEwbPmzROagg==/com.joy.dreams-_3gKnvwVkixqDYaLkfgxvA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: ccc8535e5325b0e400c5bed07b4f9a9b0b53bd60)
      #08 pc 0000000000e209f0  /data/app/~~udK_hURMFPtEwbPmzROagg==/com.joy.dreams-_3gKnvwVkixqDYaLkfgxvA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: ccc8535e5325b0e400c5bed07b4f9a9b0b53bd60)
      #09 pc 00000000000b3020  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264) (BuildId: 1001969d8caf747bff324cbb95af4b2e)
      #10 pc 000000000005288c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1001969d8caf747bff324cbb95af4b2e)
  at vulkan
  at libGLESv2_samsung
  at libGLESv2_samsung
  at libGLESv2_samsung
  at libGLESv2_samsung
  at libGLESv2_samsung
  at libGLESv2_samsung.EGL_ClientWaitSyncKHR (EGL_ClientWaitSyncKHR:128)
  at libunity
  at libunity
  at libc.__pthread_start(void*) (__pthread_start:264)
  at libc.__start_thread (__start_thread:64)
```

Answer (score 0):

In player setting -other setting, Graphic API is vulkan there? Check the Target API level/Minimum API level as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added the vulkan in the Graphic API. My project the Target API level was highest installed and the Minimum API Level is API Level 22 ,How should I change it.

Comment: You can update android studio